# IGrouping, Select keys into new type, and SelectManny (values) into a new collection type

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Im trying to `GroupBy` a field, `Select` keys into a new type (Country), then `SelectMany` into a new collection type (CountryPrefix)

Through intuition i've come up with the following, however , i'm having trouble "sealing the deal"

given the following class

```
public class TempPrefix
{
    public String CountryName { get; set; }
    public String Prefix { get; set; }
    public int ClassificationId { get; set; }
}
```

and  `tempPrefixes` is a `List<TempPrefix>`

```
  var countries = tempPrefixes
            .GroupBy(x => x.CountryName)
            .Select(x =>  new Country
                {
                    Name = x.Key,
                    CountryPrefixes = x.SelectMany(y => new CountryPrefix
                        {
                            ClassificationId = y.ClassificationId,
                            Prefix = y.Prefix
                        })
                });
```

Compile Error on `SelectMany`

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I'm sure this is telling me something however i'm not quite sure what it is

**ANSWER**

A stated in the accepted answer i just needed to use `Select` and not `SelectMany`

Additionally i had to convert the result to a list

```
var countries = tempPrefixes
    .GroupBy(x => x.CountryName)
    .Select(x =>  new Country
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            CountryPrefixes = x.Select(y => new CountryPrefix
                {
                    ClassificationId = y.ClassificationId,
                    Prefix = y.Prefix
                }).ToList()
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing that to `Select` instead..

In

```
CountryPrefixes = x.SelectMany(y => new CountryPrefix
                        {
                            ClassificationId = y.ClassificationId,
                            Prefix = y.Prefix
                        })
```

x is already a collection of `TempPrefix`, under the respective group, so you can simply get the `CountryPrefix` by a `Select`